# using NAT with a difference IP/range from the outside interface + proxy ARP

Tags: cisco, nat

I need to NAT the source address of the traffic from my local LAN going out of the ASA firewall.

[image]

From the diagram above, my outside interface IP on the ASA firewall is set at 192.168.12.2

q1) Am i able to set NAT on this outside interface to use another range of IP (e.g. 10.10.10.1)  as its source when routing traffic from the local LAN to Router 0 (10.10.10.2) ?

q2) if the above is achievable,  how does Router 0 know how to send to the ASA firewall ?
Does it means that the ASA firewall will reply to ARP request for 10.10.10.1 even though its physical interface is set to 192.168.12.2 ?
Does it also means that I have to turn on PROXY-ARP on the ASA firewall outside interface in order for the setup to work ?

Regards,
Noob

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to give router0 a 192.168.12.3 address and a static route for 10.10.10.1/32 to 192.168.12.2 ?

Comment: @hertitu - you are right about what i am trying to illustrate in your reply to ron. but i can't do change the router0's ip.- this is a service provider router and they require us to come in at (10.10.10.1) but due to x,y reason happens to be in the same vlan with r1 and the asa outgoing interface.

Comment: Do you have control over router1?

Comment: @hertitu nope. the router is a cpe but it belongs to the service provider

Comment: What is the end goal? Are r0 and r1 both internet facing ? What traffic needs to go via r0 and which via r1? Will r1 go away at some point in the future?

Comment: @hertitu both r0 and r1 are staying for good. they are not internet facing but lease lines connecting to our business partners' services. r0 is connected to partnerA services and, r1 is connected to partnerB services. only issue is r0 need us to come in at 10.10.10.1 when connecting to them

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the source address on the IP packets. Router0 will not ARP for an address in the range you are translating to because it knows it has no direct connection to that network. ARP only works for directly connected networks.

What you need to do is to let Router0 and Router1 know to go to `192.168.12.2` for any destination addresses in your translation range.

This is routing 101. A router gets routes into its routing table from three different ways: directly connected networks, statically configured routes, and/or a routing protocol.

Since your proposed network is not directly connected to either Router0 or Router1, you will need to either statically configure a route for it in those routers, or you will need to run a routing protocols with those routers and the ASA, and have the ASA tell those routers that it has your translation network via `192.168.12.2`.

You also need to somehow let the ASA know what networks are behind each of the other routers.

---

**Edit:**

Based on the comments below, others think you are going to have the Router0 address in a different network than the Router1 and ASA addresses to which it connects. You can't do that unless the switch is a layer-3 switch and it routes between the interface to which Router0 connects and a VLAN to which Router1 and the ASA connect.

Comment: I believe you may have misread the question,  if the NAT is using 10.10.10.1 then this is directly connected for router0 and so it *will* arp for it.

Comment: According to the diagram, the inside LAN is on the ASA. The NAT needs to happen on the ASA if the inside LAN with the 10.10.10.0 address is on the inside LAN. "_I need to NAT the source address of the traffic from my local LAN going out of the ASA firewall._"

Comment: The LAN is on the inside, yes, but the LAN is not 10.10.10.0. The LAN needs to be translated to 10.10.10.1.

Comment: You don't translate the _source address_ to the same network as the destination address. The Router0 address toward the ASA must be in the `192.168.12.x` network. If the network on the other side of Router0 is `10.10.10.x`, the inside LAN cannot be the same network, else Router0 will not send traffic out a different interface since it already knows where that network is.

Comment: You're still assuming things that are not there.  The LAN on the inside of the asa is not 10.10.10.0. The network on the other side of r0 is not 10.10.10.0. The interface of r0 towards the ASA is 10.10.10.2 and the outside  interface of the ASA  is 192.168.12.2 (and so it can successfully route via r1). So asa and r0 are in the same vlan but different subnet. now the question is, if the ASA translates the LAN to 10.10.10.1 (which *is* in the same subnet as r0), could this work?

Comment: That makes no sense. The ASA and router interfaces must be in the same network in order to communicate.

Comment: Then IMHO that last comment should be your answer.  FWIW  I agree that it's a very unusual and unconventional scenario but I'm not so sure this can't work. Need to think about this some  more...

Comment: I edited my answer. Not having connecting routers in the same network is a mistake I sometimes see rookies make when trying to run labs with too little information.

Comment: If you replace the asa with a router and use 10.10.10.1 as secondary ip address on the outside interface, would that work in your opinion?

Comment: Maybe, but a routing protocol won't work on a secondary address, so Router0 and the ASA would need to use static routes. It's an ugly thing all the way around. I don't know for sure if an ASA can use secondary addressing. I remember Cisco discussing dropping secondary addresses, and I believe it has on some devices.

Comment: Asa indeed does not support secondary addresses (which is why I said to replace it with a router). But I think doing NAT on the ASA would be similar to having a secondary ip address. Not the same (no connected route) but somewhat similar. Just wanted to throw that out there as food for thought.

Comment: @heritu - heritu is right about what I am trying to illustrate. r0 was newly added but it is a service provider router (and they are not able to change their lan interface ip - 10.10.10.2) in this case.  They need my local lan traffic to be nat to source 10.10.10.1 when sending traffic to them.

Comment: please also assume that i have no other ports in asa and i am not able to do any trunking from switch to the asa. things are as it is right now - r0 in the same vlan but different subnet - would it work if i nat the local lan ip to 10.10.10.1 when going out to r0 (10.10.10.2)

Comment: No. In that case, the routers on the same layer-2 network need to be on the same layer-3 network in order to communicate. Having directly connected routers (in this case, the ASA is a router, too) with the directly connected interfaces in different networks is a rookie mistake.

Comment: @RonMaupin - to sidetrack -> can a router support doing nat using a different ip range/mask then what is configured on the outside interface ?

Comment: @Noob, it sounds like you need a NAT router with three interfaces to replace the layer-2 switch. Are you running active/standby with the ISPs. Trying to do active/active will require a lot more than you are trying to do. Yes, a router can do that. If your router interface is in the same network as the other router, and the other router knows to send traffic for the other network to your router, then that works. You just can't really "split" a network. Your problem is that the ISP router thinks it is directly connected to that network, and it will not send the traffic to the ASA interface.

Comment: @RonMaupin - the issue is that all was well until r0 decided to came in. R0 was suppose to be in the 192.168.12.0/24 network (same with r1). But due to some miscomm, it has to be configured as 10.10.10.2. Traffic towards R0 need to be coming with the source of 10.10.10.1. Thus i am thinking to use NAT to do so but i am not sure if i can use a different range then what is allocated physically on the asa external interface. Furthermore, how does R0 (thinking it's connected to the 10.10.10.0/24) subnet, talks to the ASA - the ASA must reply arp request from Router0 in order for all these to work

Comment: "_how does R0 (thinking that it is in the 10.10.10.0/24) subnet, talks to the ASA_" It doesn't; that's the problem. You could replace the layer-2 switch with a layer-3 router, and try to work it that way. I really can't tell which are public, and which are private addresses in your whole network, so I can't give you a solution. You probably want to get a consultant in there to help, or force the ISP for the new connection to do what you want. I assume that ISP wants your money, and you can try to leverage that.

Comment: "how does R0 (thinking that it is in the 10.10.10.0/24) subnet, talks to the ASA" It doesn't;  -- that the reason why i am saying, if i setup nat on the asa external interface to use 10.10.10.1 + proxy arp - will the asa reply to arp request for 10.10.10.1 from R0 ?

Comment: Proxy ARP is a _huge_ security risk, especially on a public network. You really, _really_, **_really_** don't want to go down that road.

Comment: @RonMaupin https://lkhill.com/proxy-arp-sucks/#lightbox/3/  seems like nat on a different range from the outbound interface is allow, but this is given that the segment between the outbound interface and the uplink router is still within the same subnet range.

Comment: **Proxy ARP is a security risk.** I don't know how else to phrase it. It is identified as a _huge_ security risk. That is nothing I would ever recommend to anyone, especially on a publicly addressed network. If you want to put your whole business at risk, then feel free, but you should run this by your security people and auditors first.

Comment: Cisco says this about proxy ARP: "_Security can be undermined. A machine can claim to be another in order to intercept packets, an act called 'spoofing.'_"

Comment: I think that Ricky Beam said it best: "_Indeed. You can stop right at the mention of proxy-arp. That's a last ditch maneuver that should never be done. If you know exactly what you're doing, fine, but if you have to ask anyone anything about it, DON'T. I have a few proxy-arp stubs in my DC, but I know exactly why. – Ricky Beam Jul 16 at 0:22_"

Comment: I guess I've only been in scenarios where proxy arp was harmless, so I'm eager to understand how exactly it is a threat here, in this specific scenario? For example, who could possibly spoof what?